# How is HttpResponseRedirectBase class being called when I call HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out how `HttpResponseRedirectBase` is being called when I call this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page, context)
```

I believe this question has more to do with python than Django but I cannot find the answer to this question.I understand that in python the derived class needs to explicitly call the `__init__` of the base class in order to initialize it.So far this is what I have seen

```
class HttpResponseRedirect(HttpResponseRedirectBase):
    status_code = 302
```

Now my question is how is the initializer of  `HttpResponseRedirectBase` being called here ? I tried simulating the above situation

```
class foo(object) :
  def __init__(self,par):
    print "Inside foo constructor"

class bar(foo):
  status_code = 302

b = bar(23)
```

I am not sure how **init** of foo will be called in this case ? In this case I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Any help clearing this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to inherit a `function`

```
class bar(foo):
```

Where `foo` is function.Did you mean

```
class foo(object) :
  def __init__(self,par):
    print "Inside foo constructor"
```